# How to uninstall IE Addon

Tags: c#, registry, uninstallation, ieaddon

I am building an IE Addon in C#. I uninstall my addon using Programs and Features. But it doesn't work out. The toolbar stays there on the browser. Tried Manage Addons from Tool Menu in IE. It displays Unavailable, but doesn't give an option to Remove or Uninstall it. I am unable to remove it fully. Also, when I rebuild my SetUp and reinstall it, it's not reflecting the changes as the old one is still there.
Even I deleted the Keys from the Registry.
Also there are other Addons which aren't built by me and still show the same behaviour.

Please see the Screenshot.
[image: Screenshot from Manage Addons in IE]

Please guide me to uninstall or say remove these.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some url.May be it can help you.

http://www.ehow.com/how_4424435_uninstall-internet-explorer-add_ons.html

http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/internet-explorer/209308-uninstalling-ie-7-add-ons.html

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got a link, please try this, it worked for me
http://windowsxp.mvps.org/toolbarcop.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try using Autoruns (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).